# How to text-align an svg element inside a div

Tags: html, css

I would just like to know why `text-align: right` is not moving the svg to the right? It is moving the button to the right. I need the svg to sit above the button on the right.

```css
svg {
    display: block
}

polygon {
    fill: red;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <svg height="20" width="20">
        <polygon points="10,0 20,20 0,20"/>
    </svg>
    <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have the SVG as a block level element.  Block's don't text-align.  You could float it right, or just simply give it display: inline-block.  See below.

```css
svg {
    display: inline-block
}

polygon {
    fill: red;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <svg height="20" width="20">
        <polygon points="10,0 20,20 0,20"/>
    </svg>
    <div>
    <button>Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:  You can wrap the button in a div (a block level element).  Alternatively, you can just put in a line-break (br) in between the two elements.**

Comment: I need the arrow to be ABOVE the button on the right side hey

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Eric has explained you well why SVG is not moving to the right. 
Another solution to resolve your problem is to use flexbox.

```
/*svg {
    display: block
}*/

polygon {
    fill: red;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;

    /* I added only these rules */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```css
/*svg {
    display: block
}*/

polygon {
    fill: red;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <svg height="20" width="20">
        <polygon points="10,0 20,20 0,20"/>
    </svg>
    <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

svg is not moving right as you are aligning any text as right, not svg as it is set as display: Block  instead of display: inline-block;

try:

```
float: right;
```

on the svg.

Comment: I need the arrow to be ABOVE the button on the right side hey

Answer (score 0):

As you have editted your post and you want both objects on the right side above eachother I have added one extra div arround it. This div will `float:right;` which means that it'll be positioned to the right side of the page.

Everything in the div will just position under each other.

```css
.right-section { float:right; }

svg { margin-left:10px; display:block; }

polygon {
    fill: red;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="right-section">
      <svg height="20" width="20">
          <polygon points="10,0 20,20 0,20"/>
      </svg>
      <button>Test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also added `margin-left:10px;` to the `svg { }` to make sure the arrow is in the center of the button.